# exp publish cannot update on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am working on detached app, the app can run successfully on both IOS and Android. While, after changing some JS code, I run `exp publish`, only on Android, it cannot receive the OTA updates. I am using the default release channel, and sdk Version is 28.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the slug in the app.json file. This has to the be the same slug as the one you had when you initially uploaded the apk to the google play store. I had the same problem. So check the credentials in the app.json are the same as when you uploaded the apk to the google play store.